# How do I test for exceptions in Python PyTAP?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, testing

I am using Python PyTAP:
http://git.codesimply.com/?p=PyTAP.git

I can use the `ok` function to test truths (1 == 1, etc). However, I would like to test if a function is raising an exception properly. How would I be able to do that? Thanks!

Edit:

The function checks a list of strings. If the strings fit certain conditions, then a exception is raised. If those conditions are not met, then the function returns some values.

Comment: What is the function/what does it do? Do you want it to always be raising an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try it outside of PyTAP:

```
try:
  my_func()
  print "Exception not raised."
except Exception, e:
  print "Exception \"" + str(e) + "\" raised."
```

If you're already catching your exception within `my_func`, you could just put a `print` statement in the `except` clause. This assumes you can actually modify the code, of course.

Comment: I can't modify the code. SO what I think I will do is have a try-except around that function. In each block, I store something to a variable. Then after that try-except block, I use the `ok` function to validate what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think `try:` and `except:` statements would be your best bet.